# Load data into GPU directly using PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, dataloader

In training loop, I load a batch of data into CPU and then transfer it to GPU:

```
import torch.utils as utils

train_loader = utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)

for inputs, labels in train_loader:
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
```

This way of loading data is very time-consuming. Any way to directly load data into GPU without transfer step ?

Comment: On what basis you are saying it is time-consuming? I think this is standard practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load all the data to in tensor than move it yo GPU memory.(assuming that you have enough memory) When you need it use the one inside the tensor which is already at GPU memory. Hope it helps.

Comment: @PeterJulian After preparing the tensor which contains your data, you can move that to the GPU using `your_data = your_data.to(device)` You can find some examples and details [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/load-entire-dataset-on-gpu/79165).

Comment: Thanks, I know that you can load tensors to the device with that. I meant, is there any command to load the whole data set to the GPU such that you do not have to call to(device) on every batch. Not sure how expensive that is but it's always an operation from CPU to GPU and this may be noticeable in compute, esp. on smaller networks/data sets.

Answer (score 10):

@PeterJulian first of all thanks for the reply. As far as I know there is no single line command for loading a whole dataset to GPU. Actually in my reply I meant to use .to(device) in the `__init__`  of the data loader. There are some examples in the link that I had shared previously. Also, I left an example data loader code below. Hope both the examples in the link and the code below helps.

```
class SampleDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, device='cuda'):
        super(SampleDataset, self).__init__()
        self.data = torch.ones(1000)
        self.data = self.data.to(device)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        element = self.data[i]
        return element
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant just load training data into tensor directly for many deep learning problems. Many times you need to use DataLoader to generate new augmentated data while training is ongoing with other free multiprocessors.

That is the advantage of DataLoader. Via setting your transform arguments strategically, your training data differs slightly every epoch, assisting with regularization.

Of course if comprehensive Data augmentation while training is on the round isn't needed and you have enough memory to load the entire static training data as one tensor object, then that would definitely fix your problem.

just set tensorObject.to(device), but you lose the benefits of dataloaders.

Answer (score 0):

**May I propose the following work around?**

> In a separate script, long before any modeling is to take place, pay the fixed cost of transferring your data in (possibly quite large) batches to GPU, and saving them on GPU using `torch.save` so that, in the future, you can load them directly onto GPU using `torch.load`.

Specifically, you can do this by calling `torch.save(batch_j,f"path_{j}.pt")` on the j-th batch of data, which should be in GPU when you save it (i.e., `batch_j` should have `batch_j.device.type=="cuda"` when you call `torch.save` on it). In the future, because it was saved directly from GPU, calling `torch.load(f"path_{j}.pt")` will load *directly and efficiently to GPU* (quote: "When you call `torch.load()` on a file which contains GPU tensors, those tensors will be loaded to GPU by default." source: `https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html`).

(Of course, the details regarding how you want to distribute the batches, how to best incorporate `torch.load` into the `__getitem__` method, etc. will still need to be thought through, taking into account your specific use case).