# How to use GPU for training instead of CPU?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

I was replicating the code which is fine-tuned for Domain Adaptation. This is the main link to the post for more details:

(https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tuning-for-domain-adaptation-in-nlp-c47def356fd6)

The code is as such:

```
!pip install -q transformers
!pip install -q datasets

import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import transformers
from datasets import Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from transformers import AutoModelForMaskedLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig
from transformers import BertForMaskedLM, DistilBertForMaskedLM
from transformers import BertTokenizer, DistilBertTokenizer
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, RobertaForMaskedLM
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer

# HYPERPARAMS
SEED_SPLIT = 0
SEED_TRAIN = 0

MAX_SEQ_LEN = 128
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 16
EVAL_BATCH_SIZE = 16
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-5 
LR_WARMUP_STEPS = 100
WEIGHT_DECAY = 0.01

# load data
dtf_mlm = pd.read_csv('data/jigsaw_train.csv', nrows=1000)
dtf_mlm = dtf_mlm[dtf_mlm["target"] < 0.5]
dtf_mlm = dtf_mlm.rename(columns={"comment_text": "text"})


# Train/Valid Split
df_train, df_valid = train_test_split(
    dtf_mlm, test_size=0.15, random_state=SEED_SPLIT
)

len(df_train), len(df_valid)

# Convert to Dataset object
train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df_train[['text']].dropna())
valid_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df_valid[['text']].dropna())

#Model Selection Part
MODEL = 'bert'
bert_type = 'bert-base-cased'

TokenizerClass = BertTokenizer
ModelClass = BertForMaskedLM 


#Tokenization Part
tokenizer = TokenizerClass.from_pretrained(
            bert_type, use_fast=True, do_lower_case=False, max_len=MAX_SEQ_LEN
            )
model = ModelClass.from_pretrained(bert_type)


def tokenize_function(row):
    return tokenizer(
        row['text'],
        padding='max_length',
        truncation=True,
        max_length=MAX_SEQ_LEN,
        return_special_tokens_mask=True)
  
column_names = train_dataset.column_names

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    tokenize_function,
    batched=True,
    num_proc=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
    remove_columns=column_names,
)

valid_dataset = valid_dataset.map(
    tokenize_function,
    batched=True,
    num_proc=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
    remove_columns=column_names,
)


#Training and Model Saving Part
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=True, mlm_probability=0.15
)


steps_per_epoch = int(len(train_dataset) / TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./bert-news',
    logging_dir='./LMlogs',             
    num_train_epochs=2,
    do_train=True,
    do_eval=True,
    per_device_train_batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=EVAL_BATCH_SIZE,
    warmup_steps=LR_WARMUP_STEPS,
    save_steps=steps_per_epoch,
    save_total_limit=3,
    weight_decay=WEIGHT_DECAY,
    learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, 
    evaluation_strategy='epoch',
    save_strategy='epoch',
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model='loss', 
    greater_is_better=False,
    seed=SEED_TRAIN
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=valid_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)

trainer.train()
trainer.save_model("SavedModel/TestModel") #save your custom model
```

And this is the GPU that I am using:
[image: NVDIA RTX A6000]

I want to use the GPU for training the model on about 1.5 million comments.

I tried doing this:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


#Setting the tokenizer and the model
tokenizer = TokenizerClass.from_pretrained(
            bert_type, use_fast=True, do_lower_case=False, max_len=MAX_SEQ_LEN
            )
model = ModelClass.from_pretrained(bert_type).to(device)
```

But I am unsure how to send the inputs and tokens to the GPU.

Feel free to give your advice, and *I don't owe this code*, shout out to **Marcello Politi**. Thanks!

Comment: you need to define a dataloader for pytorch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111599/load-data-into-gpu-directly-using-pytorch

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried but have no luck. Could you give some hints based on the above code?

Comment: After you load the dataset try to add `.to('cuda')` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061779/pytorch-when-do-i-need-to-use-todevice-on-a-model-or-tensor

Comment: Thanks! I added that, and I trained it in the google colab.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, could you please also mark the question as "accepted?" https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333443106/figure/fig1/AS:766741500153860@1559816827830/An-example-of-stack-overflow-Q-A-post.png
Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you load the dataset you should add:

```py
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
train_dataset = train_dataset.to(device)
```